# Meta Stack Overflow is disorienting and causing me headaches

Tags: bug, status-completed, usability

Everybody go to the new questions view and then come back. I will wait for you.

Now that you're back you're surely dizzy and confused because of how screwed up that view is. It's an atrocity that a visual bug like this is allowed to exist. Come on, people. It's 2010: we have HTML 5, CSS 3, Red Sox 6.

[image: Everything is wrong]

This has to be stopped here and now. I come to this site to answer questions and to make fun of Jeff. I look for things to line up so that I can position myself to seize the day.

Right when I'm about to grab life by the neck and choke it to death the misaligned right-hand-side of Meta completely turns me around. In my moment of weakness life escapes my grasp and now I have to move to Toronto.

(On the other hand I kinda wanted to move to Toronto, or at least that region, anyway. But I digress.)

Point is, we need to fix this issue. What if a goose looks at it and forgets what direction south is? The entire species would die! Whales, ducks, alligators, Slovenia, all of them would lose their way!

You have the chance to prevent all of this from happening. The power is in your hands. Choose wisely, Atwood's Angels.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is there and actual issue here?

Comment: Is it normal to actually, y'know, *draw* emoticons? Wouldn't it be easier to just draw a little face?

Comment: I think it's all in Double Welbog's head. That's what happens when you clone yourself, then kill and eat the clone to gain its power.

Comment: So, that's a no, this is just unintelligible ramblings...@Welbog, you should be more careful who you buy your drugs from..

Comment: @jjjjjguys: Yeah, the things on the side don't line up and it's disorienting the hell out of me.

Comment: @Double.  Ok, I see what you mean.  But it doesn't bother me at all.

Comment: @jayjay: I am very sensitive to alignment and orientation. I just plain can't navigate through gay pride parades because of all of the different orientations.

Comment: Lines are for losers! The site must be arranged in CIRCLES!

Comment: @Lady - +1 just for spelling "losers" right.

Comment: Dang, you went and made my OCD kick in.  Now I'll never be able to look at any other part of the page.

Comment: @tvan, you should form a self-help group with Welbog.

Comment: @lady - should we just use the Mental States stackexchange site or do you think we should create a new proposal for just OCD.  I can pretty much guarantee that anyone who joins will participate.

Comment: @tvan: If Ubuntu needs its own proposal, than OCD for sure.

Comment: @tvan - I am so tempted to suggest a site in Area51 called "Forum Addicts - for people who obsessively participate in Internet forums."

Comment: Ooh - or how about "Overcoming Internet Addiction - A Q&A site to help Internet addicts spend less time online".

Comment: My sympathy goes out to the citizens of Toronto.  Misaligned on mine, Firefox 3.6.8

Comment: @Jon: Wait, an internet site that draws revenues from its visitors and tries to help them get *off* the internet? How clever, i am surprised no-one hit the market with that yet.

Comment: @Ladybug: a line is just a circle with infinite radius! The site must be arranged in KLEIN BOTTLES THE `<CENTER>` CANNOT HOLD

Answer (score 10):

Lines up fine for me, too:

[image]

Comment: Something is wrong with your picture. I think there's a blurry image of a website under that straight red line. You should totally drop that.

Comment: @balpha: and use jQuery?

Answer (score 5):

Looks pretty lined up here.

[image]

Comment: What does the pony do there?

Comment: @Lady - obviously, it pierces the sky. http://www.princessunicorndoll.com/

Comment: **AHHH, MY EYES! CURSE YOU, @tvan, CURSE!**

Comment: *"Do not play with Princess Unicorn if you are allergic to lead based paint"*

Answer (score 2):

Lines up for me...
[image]

(This is a question page.  But the things all line up the same on the newest question page as well.)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 6.0.495.0 dev. What are you using? Maybe this is a browser-specific issue.

Comment: @Double, MSPaint `:P`

Comment: @Double, you had to go and mention Chrome's dev channel.  Now Jeff will just come in with a [status-declined] and a comment about not supporting beta browsers. (;

Comment: @rchern: The "dev" is short for "deviant", not "beta".

Comment: @double All this time, I thought it was just for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is mine on Firefox 3.6.8:

[image]